# Proof that $\inf\{n\geq 0: Y_{n+1}>a\}$ is a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes

> Let $(E_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of events s.t. $E_n\in F_n$ for all $n$. Then define $$Y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \Bbb{P}(E_k|F_{k-1})$$ and define for every $a>0$, $t_a=\inf\{n\geq 0: Y_{n+1}>a\}$. I want to show that this is a stopping time.

My idea was the following:

**Proof** Let $a>0$ arbitrary and pick $n\in \Bbb{N}$ then $$\begin{align}\{t_a=n\}&=\{\inf\{n\geq 0: Y_{n+1}>a\}=n\}\\&=\{Y_0\leq a,...,Y_n\leq a,Y_{n+1}>a\}\\&=\left(\bigcup_{k=0}^n Y_k^{-1}\left((-\infty,a]\right)\right)\cup \left(Y_{n+1}^{-1}((-\infty, a])\right)^c\end{align}$$But now we remark that $Y_k$ are $F_{k-1}\subset F_n$ measurable. But in particular also $Y_{n+1}$ is $F_n$ measurable. Hence we deduce that $\{t_a=n\}\in F_n$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\{\tau_a>n\}=\{Y_{n+1}\leq a\}=\bigg\{\sum_{1\leq k\leq n+1}P(E_k|\mathscr{F}_{k-1})\leq a\bigg\}$$
Since $P(E_k|\mathscr{F}_{k-1})$ are $\mathscr{F}_n$ measurable for all $k\leq n+1$ (note $P(E_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n)$ is $\mathscr{F}_n$ measurable), then $Y_{n+1}$ is $\mathscr{F}_n$ measurable and $\{\tau_a>n\}\in \mathscr{F}_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but would my way also work?

Comment: @user123234 you should use intersections

Comment: ah I see. Is it because we are looking for all $\omega\in \Omega$ s.t. $Y_k(\omega)<a$ for $1\leq k\leq n$?